# Magento Go, referencing a JS file attached to a theme in a CMS static block?

Tags: javascript, cms, magento-go

If I want to reference a JS file in a CMS block and the js file has been attached to the theme, how is it done? The CMS block has the script:

```
<script>
Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
Galleria.run('#galleria');
</script>
```

I don't have the functionality to see where the JS are stored once they are loaded into the JS editor and library section of Magento Go.

I would omit the section but it needs to be there, so should look like:

```
<script>
Galleria.loadTheme('JS file attached to the theme');
Galleria.run('#galleria');
</script>
```

Can someone enlighten me as to the location of the JS files and how to add it?

Answer (score 1):

If I did understand your question correctly, you want to know in witch JS file the Galleria class is loaded to insert this JS and use as you want, right?

If so, all you need to do is to load some page that has this code and try to Ctrl+F af firebug search, being at the Script tabs. You can try to look for *var loadTheme* or *Galleria*, etc to see in witch .js file the galleria is located.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately I know where the JS is, its in theme > customise > JS editor.

What Im not sure is how to reference that JS file from the page Im on (static block) as I dont know the file location that its stored at in Magento Go.

For example if I place an image in the media storage, I know how to reference that in the static block as below:

<img src="{{media url="HomePage/Imgs/chair_with_mug.jpg"}}" />

The CDN is not known to me for the JS location yet.

Comment: You can use {{skin url="js/jsname.js"}}. The js file usually is usually located under skin folder... So: skin/frontend/[package]/[theme]/js/... Using the {{skin url="js/myjs.js"}} magento will point to skin/frontend/[package]/[theme]/js/myjs.js.